# list not showing when opening page from alertdialog

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working in a ionic-angular project. I am navigating from one page to another using `router.navigate`. In the next page I'm fetching an array from API and showing as list. This is working fine normally. But when I am navigating from Ionic alertdialog, this list is not showing. On refreshing the page, then the list is showing. In Page 2, `this.deals` is the actual list.

```css
// Page 2
  
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.fetchDealList();
}

fetchDealList() {
    this.storage.get('userId').then((val1) => {
      this.storage.get('Bearer').then((val2) => {
        this.getDealList(val1, val2);
      });
    });
  }

  getDealList(myuserid, tokenString) {
    let url = 'deals/bizuser';
    let data = { userId: myuserid };
    this.deals = [];
    this.restService.parseModule(data, url, tokenString)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("getDealList resp: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        const mainResp = response as any[];
        this.filterList(mainResp);
        

      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.status);
      });
  }

  filterList(mainResp){
    this.deals = mainResp.filter((data) => {
      return data.dealState == 3 && data.secondId == this.mySelectedBranchId;
    });
  }
```

```html
// Page 1

async showBranches(pos) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Branch Locations!',
      inputs: this.branchArray,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "CANCEL",
          handler: data => {
            this.alertController.dismiss();
            console.log("cancel clicked");
          }
        },
        {
          text: "OK",
          handler: data => {
            this.alertController.dismiss().then(() => {
              console.log("branchId: " + data);
              this.router.navigate(['draftdeals', { branchID: data }]);
            });
          }
        }],
      cssClass: 'alertRadioCustomCss'
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Instead of `this.router.navigate`, I use `this.navCtrl.push(NewPage);` from an alert. I don't know if this makes a difference, but it's worth a try. I also don't dismiss the alert in my "OK" handler; I simply navigate to the next page: `handler: data => {
                            this.navCtrl.push(NewPage);
                        }`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. How do you pass data to next page using navCtrl?

Comment: `this.navCtrl.push(NewPage,{param1: 123, param2: 456});` and then in the NewPage constructor: `this.myParam1 = navParams.get('param1');` with `public navParams: NavParams` in the constructor.

Comment: this.navCtrl.push does not exist in Ionic v4. I'm using `this.navCtlr.navigateForward('/draftdeals', { branchID: data });` which does not accept params other than boolean

Comment: Ah, right. I haven't used Ionic 4 yet, sorry.